# Validity of std::prev and std::next for std::list

Tags: c++, c++11, iterator, stdlist

I am storing an iterator to a list:

```
list<int> l;
l.push_back(21); l.push_back(1); l.push_back(31); l.push_back(41);

auto it = l.find(21);
```

In my algorithm, whenever I delete a node, I need to add up the adjoining elements. Something like this:

```
auto prev = std::prev(it);
auto next = std::next(it);
*prev = *prev + *next;
l.erase(it);
```

As you see, I need to ensure all boundary conditions. What values do `std::prev()` and `std::next()` return if:

- they are the first and last elements;
- or if `it` itself has become invalid at some point?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What values do `std::prev()` and `std::next()` return...

They return the `n`th (where `n` defaults to 1) predecessor or successor of the iterator `it`. See here for [[iterator.operations]](http://eel.is/c++draft/iterator.operations) /6 and /7.

> ... if they are the first and last elements; or if `it` itself has become invalid at some point?

The iterator needs to be valid before the call is made. The return value would be an invalid iterator if `it` is one of the corresponding boundary iterators; i.e. `it == begin()` for `prev(it)` and `it == end()` for `next(it)`.

The validity of `it` needs to be established before it is used as an argument to `prev()` or `next()`. [`std::prev()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/prev) and [`std::next()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/next) have no why of determining if the iterator decrement or increment would put the iterator outside the bounds of the container.

As such, it sounds like you would need to code for two boundary conditions in the erase part of the algorithm; first where `it == l.begin()` and second where `it == prev(l.end())`, and possibly a third if the element is not found (hence `it == l.end()`).

```
// only proceed it something is found...
if (it != l.end()) {
  if (it == l.begin()) {
    // nothing to do...? element removed is the first one
  }
  else if (it == std::prev(l.end()) {
    // nothing? element removed is the last one....
  }
  else {
    auto prev = std::prev(it);
    auto next = std::next(it);
    *prev = *prev + *next;
  }
  l.erase(it); // remove the found element...
}
```